# Android Out of memory small bitmap

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, bitmap

im getting an out of memory error only occasionall when using the following code

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    // CODE FOR PUTTING BITMAP ON BACKGROUND
    String pathName = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString()
            + "/Backgrounds/0.png";
    Resources res = getResources();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName);
    BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(res, bitmap);
    View view = findViewById(R.id.screen1);
    view.setBackgroundDrawable(bd);
    }
```

The bitmap is only 310k and its the same bitmap on all my activity's (10 )

It tends to happen when switching from one activity to another in rapid succession.

any ideas how to make it more efficient?

Any help is appreciated

Mark

Comment: `bitmap is only 310k`. You mean 'the png file is only 310KB'!? The bitmap will occupy much more memory.

Comment: 310kb is *compressed* size of your png image. when it is loaded into memory, it is called **in memory** size and that may be different (generally more). What causes OOM is **in memory** size of your bitmap. You should check how much memory you are trying to allocate.
Suggestion: Use image loading libraries for android.

Comment: You can add "System.gc();" command to force android garbage collector to clear memory.

Comment: Scale the png down. What is its resolution? Why not assign the bitmap directly? For what a conversion to Drawable is needed?

Comment: sorry for my ignorance when I say bitmap i class png, jpg as a bitmap i mean picture the resoloution of the picture is 1280 x 800 same size as my tablet the file size is 310k i trying to set it as a background but the picture needs to be on the sd card so it can be changed.

Comment: Thanks acac97 using System.gc() before each time i go to a new activity seems to have solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter how big your bitmap is most likely.  When you get an OOM that means the entire system is out of memory.  FOr example, if you have a 10MB heap and I allocate 9.999 MB then allocate 100 bytes, the 100 bytes will throw the exception (because that's when its actually out of memory).  THe real problem was the first allocations.

Using System.gc is a horrible hack and doesn't actually fix your problem-  it just delays you seeing it at best.  You have a memory leak.  You need to fix this memory leak, if not now then eventually.  The leak is almost certainly about a leaked reference to your Activity object.  Go back into your app, run some heap profilers, and figure out where your leak is.